# SharePoint Lists: send list view via mail once a month

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I try to send a list view once a month via. mail using power automate.

I usually start with a "SharePoint – Get items" to get the list view I want. after that, I kind of struggle. everything I tried ended in errors. I looked up alot online, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. There are many ways to do it (I guess), but nothing really did the trick for me

Like I dont need a lot. I only need this done once a month so people get reminded to look at it. formatting the list view for an email is probably pretty hard, but in my head it sounds so easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [run flows on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks) as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was able to do that part on my own, what I'm missing is sending the result via. mail (either embedded as html table or as a document attached in this mail)

Comment: Please refer to this article:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-format-html-table-using-microsoft-flow-and-sharepoint-online/